# How to update a cloned branch

Tags: git, github

I am cloning a branch using the below code

`git clone -b branch remote_repo`

It clones fine, but now I would like to update it as the branch owner changed code. How do I go about doing that.

Comment: Did you try `git fetch` or `git pull`?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably do `git pull`

But if you already changed something in the cloned repo, then you can do this

```
git fetch --all
```

And then

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

But if you're on any other branch , then `git reset --hard origin/<yourbranch>`